# jasny bootstrap file upload, file not changed

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, jasny-bootstrap

I'm using

> jasny bootstrap file upload

with PHP. I've been all over the forums and documents but couldn't solve my problem.

See, when user uploads an image(image is required field by the way so user cannot save without assigning a photo), I store image's path to db and save photo to user's profile, no problem so far.

But when updating user info, that's where problem starts. I check if user has photo, and if user has a photo, i show that photo (also no problem) but when i save without changing photo, program acts like as if no photo is assigned("this field is required").

I think the problem is when I manually(in code) show photo in HTML part it's seen as

```
<img id="uploaded_img" src="_uploads/user_photo/2SVbjvWESnZD.png">
```

But when I choose to pick photo using button

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" style="max-height: 150px;">
```

Some kind of encrypted data,
Anyone face this problem before ?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin generates a preview of the selected file. The strange string you see in the image source is in fact the whole image. This is correct and doesn't have anything to do with your problem.

If you add the required attribute to the `<input type="file">` element, you're telling that the user is required to select a file. However if the user already has a photo uploaded, he's **not** required to select a new image. So in that case, you need to omit the required attribute.

In short, you need to do something like

```
<input type="file" <?php if (!isset($photo)) echo 'required'; ?> name="photo">
```

Comment: Well, I've found the solution to my problem. If you can see this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050193/set-value-with-prototype-fails-inside-prototype-js